# Ionic + Capacitor | Getting a Device UUID in iOS device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

I'm trying to register every device of my application linking ionic, Firebase and Amazon SNS. More specifically when the users logs in a TokenDTO containing:

1. deviceToken: string
2. deviceUuid: string
3. osType : string *[used to distinguish iOS and Android]*

must be sent to the Backend in order to register the deviceToken on an Amazon SNS Topic.
The only problem I am experiencing is trying to uniquely identify an **iOS device**. On Android everything works as expected (using **@ionic-native/unique-device-idd**) but this returns null when used in an iOS environment. Can someone please help with this? Thank you so much in advance!

Here's my code:

```
registerTokenOnSNS(tokenString): any {
    let tokenDTO: TokenDTO = {
        deviceToken: '',
        imei: '',
        osType: '',
    };
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
        tokenDTO.osType = 'Android';
    } else {
        tokenDTO.osType = 'iOS';
    }
    tokenDTO.deviceToken = tokenString;
    tokenDTO.imei = this.device.uuid

    return this.http.post<Response>(this.apiBaseUrl + '/register-endpoint', JSON.stringify(tokenDTO)).pipe(
        map((result) => {
            console.log('BE Received Token');
            return result.body;
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: check this link 'https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/device' and use `uuid` from `Device.getInfo`

Comment: are you import `import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';` in app.module.ts file???

Comment: @maunacode_ sorry this is off topic, can you link me to a guide you followed to setup ionic, firebase and sns for android? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Every plugin need to wait device ready. User device ready function and call get uuid function.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
  private device: Device,
  private platform: Platform
) {
 this.getDevice();
}
async getDevice(){
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {      
      const id = this.device.uuid;
    })
 }
  checkLogout() {
    this.commonService.checkLogout();
 }
}
```

This is works for me.